# Hausdorff dimension of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(2^nx)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, dimension-theory-analysis

> Calculate the Hausdorff dimension,$\dim_H$ of $$S=\{x\in(0,1):\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin2^nx=0\}$$

By definition We need to find the minimal $\alpha$ s.t $\sum_{i\in I}|U_i|^\alpha$ is minimal where $U_i$ is an open cover for the set.

On the other hand, I'm not sure it exists since the function diverges when $n\to\infty$. How can I find the dimension or prove that it doesn't exist?

Comment: The function doesn't always diverge -- at least if $x$ is a multiple of $\pi/2^k$ for some $k$, then it is eventually the constant $0$. (It is usually implicit in the choice $n$ for the variable that it ranges over integers only).

Comment: Try to find a different characterisation of the set of points $x$ for which $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sin (2^nx) = 0$.

Comment: It seems to me that $S=\{x\in(0,1)\mid 2^nx=k\pi\text{ for some integers }k,n>0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, alright so if I understand correct $S=\{x\in(0,1):x=\frac{\pi}{2^{k}},k\ge n\}$?

Comment: No, $n$ is not a "free" variable in the definition of $S$. That's like asking to define $\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)$ in terms of $i$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ,so the dimension of this set is equal to the dimension of its closure (which is $[0,1]$), i.e 1?

Comment: Does it help if we write $$ S = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty}\bigcup_{l\in \Bbb{Z}} \left( \frac{\pi l - \delta_{k}}{2^{m}}, \frac{\pi l + \delta_{k}}{2^{m}} \right), $$ if $\delta_k$ is any sequence of positive real numbers converging to zero?

Comment: Sorry, don't know the dimension question, was just able to try to help you understand $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the hint by Daniel Fischer: 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin 2^n x = 0 \iff \exists n\  \sin 2^n x=0  \tag{1}
$$
The set of $x$ that satisfy the condition on the right is countable.

To prove (1), observe that if $|\sin y|\le 0.1$ then $|\cos y|\ge0.9$, so $|\sin 2y|\ge 1.8|\sin y|$. Thus, if for some $n$ the value of $|\sin 2^n x|$ is small but not zero, it will grow for a while and will not be that small.